# Enviar una variable al momento de elegir una opción de un input con la función autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un input con la función `autocomplete` de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) donde me extrae los nombres de la tabla 'TECNICO'.

Lo que quiero es que (si elijo algún nombre en el input y realizo un submit), este campo no me guarde como valor el nombre elegido sino la **cédula** de esta persona para una posterior consulta.

Aclaro que la tabla 'TECNICO' tiene el campo de nombre y cédula.

¿Es posible realizar esto, o el input siempre quedará con el valor del nombre elegido?

Adjunto mi código php y js de como estoy realizando el proceso:

```html
<?php
include'conexion.php';//Conexion a las bases de datos

$arreglo_php = array('TODOS');//se le agrega la opcion "TODOS" al array $arreglo_php para usarlo posteriormente en la funcion (autocomplete). 
  $consulta=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM generador2.TECNICO WHERE estado='A'");//Consulta de todo el personal de la empresa que se encuentran activos.
  while($fila=$consulta->fetch_array())
  {
    $nombre=$fila['nombre'];  
    array_push($arreglo_php, $nombre);//se cargan los resultados de la consulta al array $arreglo_php.                
  }

?>
```

```js
 <script>

        $(function () {/*funcion para autocompletar busqueda de usuarios*/
         var vec_pal = new Array();
         <?php foreach ($arreglo_php as $arreglo_php){ //Bucle para recorrer el array $arreglo_php ?>
                    vec_pal.push('<?php echo $arreglo_php; ?>');//se cargan del array en la variable vec_pal 
         <?php } ?>
                $("#personal1").autocomplete({//al input '#personal1' se le llama la funcion 'autocomplete'. 
                    source: vec_pal //se extraen los datos de la variable vec_pal al momento de realizar una busqueda.
                });                             
           });
           </script>
```

Adjunto imagen del input con la función 'autocomplete'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```js
    var tecnicos = [
      { value: "Edgar Mauricio Torres", cedula: "cedula1"},
      { value:"Edgar Arenas", cedula: "cedula2" },
      { value:"Luis Edgar Cardenas", cedula: "cedula3" },
      { value:"Beltran", cedula: "cedula4" }
    ];
    $("#tecnicos").autocomplete({
      source: tecnicos,
      select: ( event, ui ) => {
        let cedula = ui.item.cedula;
        
        //Seteamos el attr cedula al campo #tecnicos
        $("#tecnicos").attr("cedula", cedula);
        
      }
    });
    
    $("#enviar").on("click",() => {
      alert("la cedula es : "+$("#tecnicos").attr("cedula"))
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tecnicos">Tecnicos: </label>
  <input id="tecnicos">
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="enviar">
</div>
```

Si te fijas cree un array **tecnicos** con los atributos por cada técnico de **value** donde estará el nombre del técnico cuando selecciones uno de ellos y el atributo **cedula** donde te traes la cédula de cada uno de ellos. En el **autocomplete** use el método **select** para indicar cuando selecciones un técnico obtuvieses y setearas al campo **#tecnicos** el atributo **cedula**, luego de setarlo con el botón **submit** al darle **click** obtengo el atributo **cedula** previamente seteado cuando seleccione uno, espero te sirva.